# How to use WCF service to support Web Application as well as Mobile Application?

Tags: c#, android, .net, wcf

I want to develop a Web application with `WCF` service that supports not only My web application but Mobile Application as well which is doing all the manipulation using `JSON`.

So can someone suggest the best architecture for it and how to implement it?

**Update**

Here is what i have tried so far

**1) This is the structure of my application**

[image]

**2) IHelloService.cs**

[image]

**3) HelloService.svc**

[image]

**4) Business Logic in Factory - ServiceProfile.cs**

[image]

**4) Entity - Profile.cs**

[image]

**5) Calling a Service on Page**

[image]

This will work fine!! but when i access this service through android app that must return JSON. That is where i got stuck. how to use same service that can be used both side.

To test this service i used ajax call as below.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Service/HelloService.svc/TestService",
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "_Profile": [{ "Name": "Aijaz from JSON" }] }),
            success: function (data) {
                $('[Id$="Label1"]').text(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {

            },
            complete: function () { }
        });
```

Comment: What You have tried so far without implementing how can you conclude which is best so before asking please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Please see the updated question @M.Yogeshwaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a restful WCF service. This service will provide data in JSON format which you can use in Web app / Mobile app.

More info: How to create such service.
http://www.compilemode.com/2015/09/creating-wcf-rest-service-to-get-json.html

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the binding details webHttpBinding. :)